# Put resultset into an array in java

Tags: java

I am using select2 with java, and I need to put `resultset` into an array named **resutls**.

here is my code:

**java**

```
public static String convertResultSetToJson(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();

        //iterate rows
        while (resultSet.next())  {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();      //extends HashMap
            //iterate columns
            for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
                String column_name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
                obj.put(column_name, resultSet.getObject(column_name).toString());
            }
            json.add(obj);
        }

        return json.toJSONString();
    }
```

and I called it like:

```
ResultSet list = connection.executeWithResult("select * from test where id::text like '%" + term + "%'");
out.print(functions.convertResultSetToJson(list));
```

**Output:**

```
[{date: "1996-12-11", systemId: "3", creator: "3", boss: "3", creatorChart: "1", subSystemId: "4",…}]
```

my question is, How to produce output like this?

```
 {results:[date: "1996-12-11", systemId: "3", creator: "3", boss: "3", creatorChart: "1", subSystemId: "4",…]}
```

Comment: add something like the following at the end: `JSONObject resultsObject = new JSONObject(); resultsObject.put('results', json); return resultsObject.toJSONString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current output is a valid JSON. This is an array of Objects.

```
[{
   date: "1996-12-11",
   systemId: "3",
   creator: "3",
   boss: "3",
   creatorChart: "1",
   subSystemId: "4"
}]
```

But what you want to achieve is not a valid JSON.

```
{results:[date: "1996-12-11", systemId: "3", creator: "3", boss: "3", creatorChart: "1", subSystemId: "4",…]}
```

As @Harald mentioned in comment, if you want to wrap your array in a wrapper object, then you can do this

```
public static String convertResultSetToJson(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int numColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();

    //iterate rows
    while (resultSet.next())  {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();      //extends HashMap
        //iterate columns
        for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
            String column_name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
            obj.put(column_name, resultSet.getObject(column_name).toString());
        }
        json.add(obj);
    }
    JSONObject resultsObject = new JSONObject();
    resultsObject.put('results', json); 
    return resultsObject.toJSONString();
}
```

This will produce the below JSON.

```
{
   results: [{
       date: "1996-12-11",
       systemId: "3",
       creator: "3",
       boss: "3",
       creatorChart: "1",
       subSystemId: "4"
   }]
}
```